# Eclipse navigation related

Tags: eclipse

So I have some refactoring working ahead of me which involves adding another parameter to a method call. This scenario doesn't allow quick fix.

Example (very simplified):

```
methodCall(arg1, arg2).anotherMethodCall();
```

Since there anotherMethodCall() exists I cant simply go to end of line and use arrows to quickly get to where I want to be for adding arg3 in the end of the parameter list for methodCall().

So if I have the cursor in methodCall, is there some way to easily navigate to the end of the parameter list of the method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's refactoring features can (mostly) automate this for you. Right-click on the method you want to add a parameter to (in your case, it would be the source of `methodCall()`), and choose **Refactor** > **Change Method Signature...**.

[image]

In the resulting dialog, use the **Add* button to add a new parameter to the method signature. The **Default value** is what will be automatically inserted into all code that already calls the method, so you can choose something reasonable, or set it something invalid (like the word FIXME) to force compile errors on each of the calling places.

[image]

Press **OK** to complete the refactoring and all of the calling code will be adjusted. If you set the **Default value** to be something that produces compile errors, you can use the *Problems* view to easily navigate directly to the problem and fix the value.

[image]